# How to get payload in event laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

In my controller I have this code.

```
event(new ExampleEvent(), ['data' => '123']);
```

the event helper has payload arguments. I'm trying to study If i get the data value using payload. In my listener

```
class ExampleListener implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  ExampleEvent  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(ExampleEvent $event)
    {
         // dd($this->payload);
    }
}
```

I want to get the data value in my payload as what I add it to my controller. I'm searching it in google on how to get the payload but failed to learn it.

Comment: have you tried to `dd($event)` in your `public function handle(ExampleEvent $event)`?

Comment: yes I try it already.  no payload found when I call it

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an object as first parameter to the event() function,
all other parameters are ignored.

You can pass your payload to your event class:

```
event(new ExampleEvent('123')); // handle the payload in the constructor
```

Listener:

```
public function handle(ExampleEvent $event)
{
     $event->data; // 123
}
```

OR

You can use a string as event name:

```
event('ExampleEvent', ['data' => '123']);
```

Listener:

```
public function handle($payload) // no type hint!
{
     //$payload == '123'
}
```